# Atomic data member calling from a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Can someone please help me understand what i am doing wrong here? 
When i make the data members of the class non atomic it is working fine.

```
class AtomicTest
{
    atomic<int> A{ 0 };
    atomic<int> B{ 0 };
public :
    AtomicTest() {  }
    void func1()
    {
        A = 1;
        cout << "func1 " << A << endl;;
    }
    void func2()
    {
        cout << "func2 " << A << endl;
        A = A + 1;
        cout << A << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    AtomicTest a;
    thread t1(&AtomicTest::func1, std::ref(a)); // I tried to move as well, i know ref would share data between two threads but i can use mutex to protect data if its needed but i cannot even call the func1

    //thread t2(&AtomicTest::func2, std::ref(a));
    t1.join();
    //t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you tried: `std::bind(&AtomicTest::func1, std::ref(a))` as the sole parameter to the thread constructor?

Comment: I sure didn't, because i had no clue why it works this way. May i know why it didn't work that way and it did using bind?

Comment: Can someone enlighten me about what the problem is? Using clang it works fine for me.

Comment: @DietmarKühl not for I. I'm using clang 3.8 (apple's port) and it pukes on [attempt to invoke a deleted constructor](http://pastebin.com/asCUA9QH). Either torquing it through `std::bind` or simply using `&a` for the second parameter eliminates the error. Happy holidays, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig: it seems clang-3.9 fixes this problem. Of course, there *is* the problem that the code does **not** compile, e.g. because it lacking necessary include directives.

Comment: I suspect it's a bug in the standard lib then, but hard saying without knowing the OP's toolchain and language-level (mine was set to `--std=c++14`, if it matters).

Comment: @WhozCraig DietmarKühl Thank you, enjoy your days!

Answer (score 0):

Due to concurrency without additional synchronization in this case it's impossible to predict program behavior:

```
A = A + 1;
```

This simple line consists of 1 atomic `load` and 1 atomic `store` operations. Even default memory order (`std::memory_order_seq_cst`) wont give you any guarantees about mixed simultaneous execution of these two threads. Standard says such case has an undefined behavior -- there is data race for your variable (it doesn't matter is it `atomic` or not).

Try to add some lock primitives (such as `std::mutex`) or change the logic to use special atomic functions (such as `fetch_add`, `exchange` etc.). See more at the [cpp-reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: I know about the mutex, and i am aware of the data race condition. All i was worried about is why that thread call didn't run. I mentioned the same as comment. I am not aware of fetch_add and exchange though. Thanks for the info

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand exact problem, and the obvious way to make the code work is to check `include`'s and and use `--std=c++11` directive. Btw (with necessary includes, directives and libs) it compiles and works pretty fine for all modern compilers (see this nice [tool](http://gcc.godbolt.org/)).